# Ошибки при миграции liquibase

Tags: java, liquibase

Загружаю приложение вместе с базой данных с помощью liquibase.
Делаю запрос на аренду квартиры и ловлю ошибку:  `ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности “contract_pkey”`. Повторяется ошибка пока не достигнет 6, потому что на данный момент у меня было всего 5 записей. Как такая ошибка(баг) исправляется?

Полная версия моего теста:

Берём код, запускаем программу, заходим в `postman`, делаем запрос по этому адресу `http://localhost:8080/auth/login` с такими данными (допустим)

```
{     "email" : "igor@mail.ru",
      "password":"igor" 
}
```

Дальше по этому адресу `http://localhost:8080/house/rent` делаем запрос с таким содержимым:

```
 {     
"startDate" : "2020-04-12",     
"endDate" : "2020-04-19",     
"houseId" : 6,     
"tenantId" : 6 
}
```

И замечаем вот эту ошибку `ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности “contract_pkey”`, делаем ещё 4 раза точно такого же запроса и на пятый ошибка пропадет.

Полная версия [кода](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent/tree/master/src), если вдруг захотите протестить.

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно. Если приложение загружается и вы делаете запросы, то это не проблема liquibase. Если оно падает на каком то ченьжсете, то как делать запрос.

Comment: Берём код, запускаем программу, заходим в postman, делаем запрос по этому адресу `http://localhost:8080/auth/login` с такими данными (допустим) `{
    "email" : "igor@mail.ru",
    "password":"igor"
}` Дальше по этому адресу `http://localhost:8080/house/rent` делаем запрос с таким содержимым: `{
    "startDate" : "2020-04-12",
    "endDate" : "2020-04-19",
    "houseId" : 6,
    "tenantId" : 6
}` И замечаем вот эту ошибку `"ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности “contract_pkey”`, делаем ещё 4 раза точно такого же запроса и на пятый пропадет.

Comment: В таблице contract уже есть 5 строк, одну сделали, значит 4 раза ещё нужно сделать и на 5 удаётся сохранить.

Comment: Похоже, что проблему нужно искать в области правильного использования GenerationType.IDENTITY с вашей базой данных, т.к. похоже что hibernate генерирует id начиная с 1. Что-то типа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107502/generatedvalue-in-postgres/42200060

Comment: @RuslanP. Там внизу под утверждённым ответом есть ещё один, говорят, что мой вариант на данный момент является верным strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY Хоть у меня сейчас так и стоит, это не избавляет от проблемы